# I want my Neovim look like that :

Tags: neovim

I want my NeoVim look like that :
https://github.com/nyoom-engineering/nyoom.nvim, how to ?

Comment: This a bit vague. I wonder if some answers provide a precise answer :-/

Comment: If you like this configuration could you tell us you don't take it as is?

Comment: What's wrong with the install instructions on the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are mainly interested by the look could install:

- the corresponding [oxocarbon](https://github.com/nyoom-engineering/oxocarbon.nvim) colorscheme and
- the [dashboard](https://github.com/nvimdev/dashboard-nvim) startup screen plugin.